# Does this pattern have a name?

Tags: design-patterns, interface

I just came to a very known website that I found pretty weird and confusing because of its onload behavior. You can see it at https://wetransfer.com and what I mean is the image below:

[image]

Just in case it's not noticeable, what I mean is that the page has a scrim which provides a quite low legibility, and behind that scrim you can see the form WeTransfer had for years. So basically, it's like a *"veil"* behind which you can see the content with which you will want to interact, but first you need to perform an action (**accept, manage cookies or a quite cryptic "No, thanks"** which, despite what the copy says, if you click it takes you to a page where you have to accept Terms of Service). In a way, it's a modal without the modal background.

Anyway, I'm not interested in the interaction possibilities or accessibility, but this sort of "veil", and would like to know if it has a name so I can look for more examples.

Comment: If it has no name, I propose "soft modal"...

Comment: I'm curious to see what other examples will emerge. For now, it seems like an "invention" of a WeTransfer designer. Or even worse, a requirement from management or marketing to still have the form visible. I would call this a "sneak peek overlay" or something like that, because it seems like it is designed to trick people into accepting the cookies so they can immediately access that form. A dark pattern perhaps?

Comment: Which criteria for a [modal window](https://ui-patterns.com/patterns/modal-windows) does this design not meet, in your opinion?

Comment: @Crissov It has no scrim, no container, and no close button (nor can it be closed). Essentially, there's nothing that resembles a modal window or allows user interaction as in a modal window.

Comment: Okay, then it’s a _modal overlay_, I guess. A true modal requires a user decision and the X/Close button is much like the “no, thanks” option here: selecting the default.